# Printing dynamic amount of elements on one report with Jasper reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I'm having trouble printing following kind of structure with JasperReports Studio/DynamicJasper:

```
Date (1.1.2015)
-action1 (text)
-action2
.
.
.
-actionN

-image1      (image-file)
-image1 text (text)
-image2
-image2 text
.
.
.
-imageN
-imageN text

Date (2.1.2015)
-action1 (text)
-action2
.
.
.
-actionN

-image1      (image-file)
-image1 text (text)
-image2
-image2 text
 .
 .
 .
-imageN
-imageN text
```

So the original idea is to print all the actions and images attached to one day, and then do the same for the next day until there are no days in the database.Basically all of this data should be printed as one report all of the described content going to detail band(s) one day after another.

Basically there can be any amount of days, and then any amount of actions and images related to each day. It would be preferred that all of this content would be printed like there was only one column: first the list of actions and then the list of images just below the actions list.

At first I was trying to implement this Jasper Studio as that was the tool I have used so far for all the other reports I have created.

Soon I realized that, this kind of structure seems not the be possible to be created with Studio, at least as far as I see it.

Problem basically is that there seems to be no way of adding dynamic amount of tables to the report created with Studio.

So that's why I started to investigate DynamicJasper.

Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, but could this kind of structure be implemented with DynamicJasper by using DynamicJasper's subreporting capabilities?

It looks like I definitely need at least two subreport definitions if I want data to be presented like it would look like #being printed on just one column".

This is because there will be two totally different kind of datatypes printed on these columns: actions are texts and images are image files.

So basically in my DynamicJasper code I would just iterate all of my dates coming from database and create 2 subreports for each day so i would end up creating 2*(the amount of days) subreports and concatenate all of these to my reportbuilder.
Does this sound like something that could work?

To be exact, I think I would print the description texts of the images on adjacent column next to images just to make things easier....

Comment: Don't agree with you this can be farliy easy created with jasper report, with the simpicity of using iReport or other visual layout sw. Dynamic jasper is useful when you do not know the structure (needs to be decided dynamically), but you have proven that you already know it.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I still need some clues on how to proceed with iReport (i've been using JasperSoft's studio though.).I would be able to do this with Studio if there would be data from only one day: I would create  a report with two tables/subreports one for the day's actions and one for the n amount of images printed just after actions. Perfect for one day. But what should I do if I there would be n amount of days still to come? I can't create tables/subreports for all of those. Maybe there is a way to reuse these tables for the next date's data and to print  just below prev date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the solution is this: "in order to print report element(s) in a loop any amount of times in one report, place the element(s) to the detail band of the report and jasper will automatically print this set of elements as many times as there are beans in the collection passed for the report as main datasource/dataAdapter."

Comment: If you feel this is the answer to your question consider accepting it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Lets do it with 2 subreport (maybe I would have done it without and used grouping) but with subreport the answer is shorter and you where already thinking about it.

**If data is on a database..**

1. In main report execute the query to find all your dates in order that you prefer.
2. In detail band put the date field formatted as you wish.
3. Below date field include a sub report, pass the date as parameter and in subreport execute query to find all actions on that date. (in its detail band put action field)
4. Below action subreport include a sub report, pass the date as parameter and in subreport execute query to find all images on that date. (in its detail band put image path and text)

Your done!, no use for any jr:table components...

Why would I do it with grouping?, because this way I could reduce number of queries that needs to be executed... but how gives about that for now ; )

---

**EDIT: OP added comment that he like to use beans**

The beans would be something like this (I have removed setters to decrease code posted)

**Main bean the DateBean**

```
public class DateBean {
    private Date date;
    private List<ActionBean> actions;
    private List<ImageBean> images;
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public List<ActionBean> getActions() {
        return actions;
    }
    public List<ImageBean> getImages() {
        return images;
    }   
}
```

**The ActionBean**

```
public class ActionBean {
    private String action;
    public String getAction() {
        return action;
    }
}
```

**The ImageBean**

This is the almost the same has the ActionBean, so no need to post code.

**Steps**

1. Fill up the `DateBean` with actions and images and put it into a `List<DateBean> datesBeans`
2. Pass a `new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(datesBeans)` as datasource to the main report.
3. In detail band put the field `$F{date}` with some formatting

> Date (1.1.2015)

4. Below, include a subreport for the actions and pass as datasource to subreport `new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{actions})` note the class of `$F{actions}` needs to be `java.util.List`.
5. In subreport's detail band put the $F{action} (hence all actions past in datasource will be automatically printed, since they are in subreport's detail band).

> -action1 (text)
>   -action2 . . .
>   -actionN

6-7. Repeat step 4 and 5 but with the `ImageBean` in another subreport

> -image1      (image-file)
>   -image1 text (text)
>   -image2
>   -image2 text . . .
>   -imageN
>   -imageN text

And thats it...

> Since the `$F{date}` and subreport's are in the `detail` band the output will be repeated on the main datasource hence the `new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(datesBeans)` for all our `DateBean`'s

Comment: Thanks, but would it be possible to create something similar with java bean collection datasources, as I'm using those instead of direct sql queries embedded to reports? Then I guess I could create something like this: pass list of DateBeans to main report, each DateBean containing two lists: actions and images of that date. Then there should be a way to somehow iterate this list of DateBeans and for each iteration pass each date's action and image lists to my subreports and print them over and over again until all dates are iterated. Seems like looping capability was the thing i was missing.

Comment: Sure, as datasource to subreport pass: new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{actionList}) where actionList is of class es. java.util.List and on DateBean you have the public List<?> getActionList(){}

Comment: Thanks again, but there is still one thing that I'm missing.:) At the moment I don't know how to make Jasper to call my subreports in a loop. Surely I could create a dataset containing all DateBeans but I'm not aware how to make Jasper to print a set of subreports (actions-table+image-table) for each DateBean. In other words. I don't know how to feed my subreports from the main report DateBean list and create a new instance of subreports for each dateBean. Making that connection is the thing I'm working on right now....

Comment: I have edit the post to show you how it can be done with beans. jasper report will call your subreports in loop (for all records in datasource) as long as these are in the detail band

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and let you know what happened. So basically what I have learned now is that there should be no need to explicitly tell jasper what elements (tables, subreports etc.) should be looped with the main report datasource. It's just about following conventions: all elements will be printed on a loop (as many times as there's beans on main datasource list) in case they are defined in detail band.

Comment: Thats correct, its easy when you start, to start putting tables jr:table in the report, but I suggest you avoid that for now... just but fields and subreport in detail band and enjoy the result.

Comment: To be honest, I was planning to use tables here instead of subreports, as in the past I have had problems with subreports in case their size grows over one page. Also there should be no need for using these tables in any other report layouts, why I don't see advantage in refactoring these to subreport-files. But in case the looping will not work if these tables are not defined in subreports, then it seems my hands are tied.:)

Comment: problems with subreports you can solve with splitType expression, anyway tables are ok... they where made to avoid these kind of subreports... its just that they often confuse the user... remeber to pass to the table the correct datasource... your sub list...

Comment: Looks like there might still be something that I don't understand. I have a dataAdapter which is returning me the DateBeans. Problem with this approach is that Jasper considers each bean on this list as a completely new report(with headers, footers an so on.) So, yes, in this way I'm able to print my dates in a "loop", but the loop is not on the level were it should be: detail band. I feel that there is still something I'm not aware of probably with the usage of datasources/datasets/subdatasets....

Comment: Make the detail band small.... the height of subreport or tables shall be small... if you have a detail band that takes the whole page you will get new page for each DateBean, note the subreports will stretch automatically

Comment: If you still have problem open a new question where you include relevant .jrxml code... and what is the problem that you have, expect result ecc..

Comment: Seem like there's no problems anymore with this one!. By reducing the size of the detail band things started to print in a way I was hoping. Thanks a lot for the help! I wish I could accept your answer, but to me the answer is somewhere in these comments: the key being: "in order to print report element(s) in a loop any amount of times in one report, place the element(s) to the detail band of the report and and jasper will automatically print these elements as many times as there are beans in the collection passed for the report as main datasource/dataAdapter."

Comment: No problem, next time I will try to answer like that ; ), have fun.,,,

Comment: Thanks, I pressed "one up" for that comment of your's that basically contains the info I was really lacking before starting this thread.

Comment: Why don't you pass your own answer and accept that?, it would always be nice to close that question...

Comment: Ok, I can do that. I'm pretty new at the forum (as with Jasper as well:), so I' don't always know what's the right way to go.

Comment: This is about question and answers you can do both... if you like a question or an answer you can upvote it (but not your own)... The secret objective of us trying to help out is to close the question... end up with an accepted answer... a solution to the question... so yes if you don't think this is an answer to your question, it would be very nice if you put down what you think is.... and since its your question you judge which is the correct one. So Accept it... you will not get any points but do some service to the community